# Getting latest build of ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Building ember-data requires Ruby 1.9. Installing this version of Ruby on MacOS Mountain Lion is not a trivial task, so I'm not keen on trying this. I wonder if anyone else could perform this build for me and send me the built package.
The version I'm currently trying to use is revision 4 and is quite different from the latest in the repository.

Comment: Hi, StackOverflow is a site to ask question, not to make special request. Instead, you could edit your question in order to ask a specific question on how to install ruby and your dependencies on macOs.

Comment: I used RVM to install 1.9.3 on OSX 10.8 and it was a trivial task...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got an ember-data example project that I try to keep updated with close-to-the-latest build:

https://github.com/dgeb/ember_data_example/tree/master/app/assets/javascripts/vendor

Comment: http://builds.emberjs.com/

Answer (score 7):

The github repo has a downloads section with the built versions. 
https://github.com/emberjs/data/downloads

**Update**

Builds are available on [builds.emberjs.com](//builds.emberjs.com)

Comment: Currently, that github downloads section seems outdated. You can grap a latest version at https://s3.amazonaws.com/builds.emberjs.com/ember-data-latest.js (... found via http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/where-do-you-download-ember-data/719/8 )

Comment: My answer is pretty old. Now that ember is stable at RC2, the best place to get builds is to just get them from www.emberjs.com

Comment: Helpful. On the GitHub repo it's not at all obvious that you can just grab the lib from downloads, and that the CDN version is a more up-to-date build. Finding where to get ember-data from the Ember site is also no picnic.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the result of running `rake dist` on the current master branch of ember-data http://cl.ly/1R0V1Y1c1p1d